# For what values of $n$ give a constant term when $\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+x\right)^n$ is expanded? Also, what is this constant term(in terms of $n$)?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Here's my question:

> What values/restrictions of $n$ give a constant term in the expansion of $$\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+x\right)^n$$? Also, for the expansions that do have a constant term, what is this constant term(in  terms of $n$)?

It seems as if only multiples of $3$ work for the values of $n$ based on the different values I have tested but I don't know how to approach a problem like this. Maybe binomial theorem? For the constant term, I have $3$ for $n=3$, $15$ for $n=6$, and $84$ for $n=9$. $3=\binom{3}{1}$, $15=\binom{6}{2}$, and $84=\binom{9}{3}$, so that makes me conclude that the constant term is $\binom{n}{n/3}$. How would I do this mathematically? What method should I use? Thanks in advance.

(I used [symbolab.com](https://www.symbolab.com/) for testing btw)

Comment: OK I changed the title

Comment: If $k$ is the power of $x^{-2}$, then we need $(-2k) + (n-k) = 0$ so $n=3k$.

Comment: @TobyMak Can you explain more on how you got to that conclusion? More specifically, I'm confused on how you got from $x^{-2}$ to $(-2k)+(n-k)=0$. Also, what is $k$? You haven't defined what $k$ is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should indeed use binomial theorem. The terms of the expansion, for $k = 0, \ldots, n$, will be
$$\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^k x^{n - k} = \binom{n}{k}x^{n - 3k}.$$
You get a (non-zero) $x^0$ term if and only if there exists some $k$ such that $n - 3k = 0$, i.e. when $n$ is divisible by $3$. As you hypothesised, this happens when $k = n/3$, so the constant term is
$$\binom{n}{n/3},$$
or $0$ when $n$ is not divisible by $3$.

Comment: Wow I didn't think it would be as easy as that. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @AidenChow You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Using the binomial theorem,

$\binom{n}{r} \cdot (\frac{1}{x^2})^{n-r}\cdot x^{r}$

We want

$-2(n-r)+r=0$

$n=\frac {3r}{2}$

$r=\frac{2n}{3}$

Since $n$ must be divisible by $3$, for $r$ to be an integer so $n$ is a multiple of $3$

$\binom{n}{2n/3}=\binom{n}{n/3}$

This statement is true because $n/3+2n/3=n$

Comment: How did you get from $n$ is a multiple of $3$ to $\binom{n}{n/3}$? It is not thoroughly explained in your answer and I am a bit confused on how you got that.

Comment: I editted my answer for clarifications

Comment: Oh I get it now thanks for the answer. You forgot a \$ after $r=\frac{2n}{3} btw.